# How to send custom parameters with Twilio SMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, callback, twilio, sms

Can someone tell me if it'spossible to send custom parameters when sending a SMS with Twilio API?

I'm sending SMS like this :

```
  var options = new CreateMessageOptions(smsToSend.PhoneNumber)
                        {
                            Body = message,
                            From = new PhoneNumber(twilioNumber),
                            ProvideFeedback = true,
                            StatusCallback = new Uri(callBackUri)
                        };
                        MessageResource.Create(options);
```

When the SMS is sent, Twilio send a callback to my application controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public TwiMLResult MessageReceive(SmsRequest request)
        {
            //Some business here
            return TwiML(new MessagingResponse());
        }
```

Problem is, I need to retrieve a custom `Id` parameter to make different business treatments.
Is there a way, when sending the SMS, to pass custom parameters that would be sent back in the Twilio's callback?

Comment: You can add URL query string parameters to the status callback URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to set any custom values, that is called out below. Each outbound SMS is assigned a unique Messaging SID which you could use to keep track of messages.

You can append a URL Query Parameter key/value to your statusCallback URL, which will be sent to your application and could be used for that purpose.

[Best Practices for SMS Message Logging](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/outbound-message-logging#additional-questions)

Comment: thanks for your time ! Any idea how i have to append that query parameter? `StatusCallback = new Uri(clabbckUri +  "?param=123")` won't work I suppose

Comment: Yes, you can add URL query string parameters to the status callback URL.